# Google Cloud Function for upload image to be used with spring boot and angular 4

Tags: spring-cloud, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to integrate Google cloud functions for uploading an image in my application which is based on spring boot and angular 4.
However based on my R&D this feature is yet available with only Node.js.
Please let me know if i can use this cloud function of uploading an image with spring boot and angular 4?

Comment: You can make a multi-part request and use google cloud storage client library in your spring-servlet.

Comment: Where do you want to upload the image?